# Redundant Web Space

Tags: redundancy

I have following problem.

My domain is registred on service "A"
My web-space (not a server) is on Godaddy.

Once a week is my service unreacheble I am sure that is godaddy problem.

My idea is to by some webspace of one different service to make my service redundant.

Note: My service is only few html files with javascrit. I dont' need to sync

But how to do it?

Whre do I have to say "there are two webspaces, if one is not reacheble, so use the other" ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I would fix the problem. Not try and patch with a plaster

Comment: @t1nt1n how? i cannot influence godaddy

Comment: have you contacted support?

Answer (score 3):

Why would you do this?  If GoDaddy's crap, find a decent hosting provider and just use them.  Don't pay for a crap service *and* a good one, then layer significant additional complexity on top with DNS failover (which is about the worst possible way to handle failover, due to client-side caching fail).

Comment: I bought their grid hosting, which is cloud like.. but it is crap... could you suggest a better hoster?

Comment: We don't do shopping questions here, for all the reasons given in [this question](http://serverfault.com/q/292013/1375).  I'd only end up recommending my employer, anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You would do this with DNS, you could either use RoundRobin DNS, so that it randomly sends the visitor to either server, or get a DNS server that switches over on fault.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare would be a decent temporary workaround.  The real solution is to get off shared hosting and onto a few real machines (if you need high availability, one machine isn't going to cut it)